# Getting field value calculated from another layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, layers, fields-attributes, coordinates

I'd like to know how to get the coordinates value of the *'layer_2'* and putting it in a field of the *'layer_1'* called `"test"`.

The coordinates value doesn't exist in a field of the *'layer_2'*, but it should be calculated in the expression in the Field Calculator of the *'layer_1'*, to putting it in the field `"test"`.

How should be the expression in the field calculator of the layer_1, to do this in QGIS?

Comment: Do the layers share some common attribute or how to know which coordinate from layer 2 to calculate for each row in layer 1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You did not mention which feature to get from the layer, so I assume the layer to get coordinates from only has one single feature. In general, to get features, geometries or attributes from another layer, you can use `get_feature()` or `get_feature_by_id()`.

```
geometry(get_feature_by_id('layer_2',1))
```

returns the geometry of `feature #1` in layer `layer_2`. To get coordinates simply add `x()` or `y()`:

```
x(geometry(get_feature_by_id('layer_2',1)))
```

Answer (score 6):

To get the coordinates of the **nearest** feature of `layer_2`, use this expression:

```
overlay_nearest('layer_2', $x)[0]
```

Replace `x` by `y` to get the y-coordinate.

Or concatenate x- and y-coordinates to get a text string output containing **both** coordinates at once:

```
overlay_nearest ('layer_2', $x || ',' ||  $y)[0]
```